# Website Link in Signature corrupted while transmission

Tags: malware, email

We placed our website link in our email signature for last one week. This link apparently converted into something corrupt, so all our mails gets bounced. We scan our web server files using ClamAV antivirus software but no infection reported. Anyone guide me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help you with so little information. How is it corrupt? Where does it go? At what point does it get corrupted? When did it get corrupted? Is it corrupted for everyone?

Comment: Also, why does a bad link in a signature result in bounced emails? Are they bouncing to all destinations?

Comment: it means URL in the body of the emails which leads to an adult-related web site and also mentioned URL appear to be compromised.This issue got report by anti-spam server of recipient side in UK.